Migrating Samba Fileserver to AD
I know I should only ask one question per post but it’s a more complex problem.
I currently have a Server with openSUSE 15.5 and Samba which works perfectly fine.
Now I am trying to migrate it to an AD Server.
My requirement is an AD for login with Windows with the preexisting Linux accounts (separate roaming profiles) and using the Linux accounts for local login, ssh login or to login from remote machines (still not sure if I should set up NIS, NFS and LDAP parallel to AD). DNS and DHCP are already working.
How I tried it to do:
The setup in YAST - Active Directory Domain Controller does not work because it couldn’t install the required packages.
Seems the package was removed after 15.4. https://bugzilla.opensuse.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1212201
I added the new repository from https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/network:/samba:/ADDC/15.5/ to install all packages.
YAST now let me run the installer but quits after setup and doesn’t finish completely.
Manually with sudo samba-tool domain provision --use-rfc2307 --interactive
I can set the AD up and I can see the server in Windows network explorer but after a reboot it is not be able to start the service again. Deleted the old smb.conf and setup created a new one.
sudo systemctl start samba-ad-dc fails and smb.service needs to be deactivated.
It seems using the removed package (probably the reason why it was removed) isn’t the proper way to set the AD up.
What are the recommended steps to migrate an existing Samba fileserver to an AD?

so you want to implement a domain controller on linux? you don't have a windows server to act as DC?

Thats correct. I always thought Samba is a replacement for a Windows server? I currently have a file server with Samba and want to change it to da DC with AD. The point that confuses me is, do I need to install the package "samba-ad-dc" (and which one from which repo because it seems it's not supported in openSUSE LEAP 15.5 anymore) and kick out the old samba package and set up everything new or can I modify my current setup but then I am not sure if its NT4 DC only or with AD.
